# Is it possible for SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) to throw?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, deadlock

I've just seen a strange behaviour in some production code where I appeared to have some deadlock. I think I've tracked it down to the following code

```
        await _registerLock.WaitAsync(_cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                response = await CreateRegistrationAsync(registration, tx).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await tx.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _registerLock.Release();
        }
```

My thinking is that the WaitAsync caused the semaphore to be entered, but an exception was thrown afterwards, meaning that the release was never called. This then means that subsequent attempts to enter block waiting for a release that will never happen.

I've seen some people write code with the WaitAsync outside the try, and others with WaitAsync inside the try.

Of course it could be throwing an ObjectDisposed exception, but my logging did not report any of that. I just had a hang until my client cancelled.

Comment: What exception *did* you see?

Comment: I didn't see any exception - it just blocked. It's inside a service fabric application, so there could be other things happening.

Comment: If you didn't see an exception, why do you think `WaitAsync` threw an exception? Trying to track down if there was really an exception or not...

Comment: I was thinking more about the ConfigureAwait throwing an exception! This service has been running for some weeks and was working ok until this morning when it started blocking. I tracked the blocking down to this method and the only way I think it can block is waiting for the semaphore or inside one of the service fabric collection methods.

Comment: Of course it can throw.  Not that hard to do either, just call its Dispose() method while the code is waiting.  Hardly where it ends, bummer if the kernel memory pool is exhausted at just the wrong time.  And a lot of other "crap happens" cases.  Stop worrying about things that your completely beyond your control.

Comment: So I really should put the wait in the finally then?

Comment: @StephenCleary - I've just edited the post to explain why I think an exception occurred. If this really is the case, then I think it means the WaitAsync should be within the try.

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause of this issue? I'm experiencing something similar so wanted to see if the issue I'm seeing is a duplicate of this issue or not before posting.

Comment: To be honest, not really. I think my SF app had some deadlocks in, but I've also taken to putting the WaitAsync inside the try, just in case! However I would post your code as well in case there is something obvious!

Comment: @NickRandell I get the same exact issue.
Maybe it is linked to the ".ConfigureAwait(false)" which makes the worker thread return to another worker thread yet the release cannot be called from another worker thread- this is my theory at least